# How to Access Oracle Database Table Column Data within Javascript in Oracle ApEx

Tags: javascript, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a column in a database table that contains several urls and I was wondering what is the best way to get these urls from the database table into a javascript function.

Example code of how to approach this would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I have attempted an answer, but really we could do with more information about how the URLs are held in the table and what you want to do with them in Javascript.

Comment: Hi Tony, the URLs are stored as http://www.google.com and what I would like to do is take say a select few of these urls, say 4 of them and add them to an array in javascript, i.e. [
        "http://www.google.com" ,"http://www.yahoo.com" ,
        "http://www.sun.com" ,"http://www.ebay.com"]

Just wondering how this would be possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Tony, if you get a chance, could you pls see if you can help with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141460/settimeout-not-working-oracle-apex

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the URLs into page items via PL/SQL code then you can access the page item values from Javascript like this:

```
url1 = $v('P1_URL1');
url2 = $v('P1_URL2');
```

For example, you could have an on-load PL/SQL process like:

```
select url1, url2
into   :p1_url1, :p1_url2
from   my_urls
where  ...;
```

To put several URLs into an array you could use the [PL/JSON library](http://oracleoss.com/faq.php?category_id=4&cat_name=PL/JSON%20-%20JSON%20Data%20Type%20for%20Oracle) - see [this example](http://database-geek.com/2009/03/25/json-in-and-out-of-oracle-json-data-type/).  Again, this would be PL/SQL code to put the JSON array into a page item which you can then access from Javascript using v$().  Or you could use AJAX as descrobed [here](http://anthonyrayner.blogspot.com/2007/06/ajax-retrieval-using-javascript-object.html).

Comment: Hi Tony, pls see my response to your query above.