# How do I pass database column values as parameters of a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript

I have a column in grid which is of hyperlink type and when I click, it should take me URL on basis of JavaScript function. Now my question is how should I pass database column name as parameter into JavaScript function. I tried something which is not fruitful.

```
<ItemTemplate>

     <td colname="time_type" >
   <a ><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TYPE_SEQ")%></a> 

         </td>


</ItemTemplate>

function Time_type(<%# Eval( "TIME_TYPE_INDICATOR" ) %>,<%# Eval( "TYPE_SEQ" ) %>){
  var url;       
if (<%# Eval( "INDICATOR" ) %> == 'O'){
url= www.something.com/<%# Eval( "TYPE_SEQ" ) %>?;

}
else if(<%# Eval( "INDICATOR" ) %> == 'T'){
url= www.something.com/<%# Eval( "TYPE_SEQ" ) %>?;

}
}
```

The function here is taking 2 database columns as parameters and based on one parameter other parameter is used as query string in URL. My javascript function is not working and I know it is not right way to pass paramaters like this.Please help. **Also please show me how to call this function on hyperlink click **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might sound stupid but why use so difficult names for function(someName,someOtherName)...
For example doesn't functions work like this:

```
function someFunction(val1,val2){
    var troll = val1+val2;
    return troll;
}
var temp = someFunction(1,2); // temp is now 3. So here is the right way to call functions and pass it parameters.
```

I'm still quite new to coding in general but I think from hyperlink it goes like this:

```
<a onClick='someFunction(someValue,someOtherValue);'></a>
```

Also I would put in quotes when assigning variable:
    url = "www.something.com/"+someVariable;

Comment: I know this works, but my question is how to pass database column values in to this function...:)

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: have you tried this: 
<a onClick='Time_type(<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TYPE_SEQ")%>);'></a>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850327/passing-variables-to-javascript-in-onclientclick this came up when searching. Might be of use to you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139678/how-to-access-oracle-database-table-column-data-within-javascript-in-oracle-apex Another post on the matter